# Большой проект с множеством модулей. Делать один репозиторий или несколько?

Tags: git, svn, контроль-версий

Есть большой проект. Сейчас все исходники хранятся на сервере. Исходники разложены по логическим каталогам. В каждом каталоге около 10 -15 проектов на c#. Всего порядка 500 таких проектов (выходит 500 dll). Сейчас разработчик заходит на сервер, берет нужный проект, правит его и выкладывает новые исходники. Компоненты одного проекта могут вызываться в другом. Т. е. есть определения связанность.

Каким образом можно внедрить Git или svn. Не ясно как сформировать репозиторий. Должен быть один большой или их следует дробить. Хотелось бы увидеть примеры внедрения таких систем, описание в статьях, например.

Comment: Уж не сотни ли почти одинаковых игр на Unity вы там делаете? ))

Comment: Нет)) просто проект состоит из различных модулей.

Comment: С точки зрения непосредственного работника (разработчика проектов), ему нужно иметь доступ ко всем суб-проектам, или только к части? Какую экономию/оптимизацию вы видите в разделении проекта на разные репозитории?

Comment: Разработчику нужен доступ только к части проектов которые могут быть в разных модулях.

Comment: Точно так же, как устроено дерево исходников Android. Кучка репозиториев и утилиты вокруг этого зоопарка, типа `repo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как это ни прискорбно, но выбор git vs svn, главным образом, зависит от интеллектуального уровня команды. svn менее гибкий, и в нем сложнее что-то натворить, и если команду устраивал вариант с общей папкой, то я бы посоветовал его, хотя бы для начала. Конвертация из svn в git делается легко.

А выбор один репозиторий vs много мелких зависит от того, насколько часто нужно вносить синхронные правки в несколько проектов, например, изменение общей библиотеки и всех использующих ее модулей. Если часто, то лучше один репозиторий. Также если все модули собраны в один проект и компилируются за один раз, то тоже лучше один репозиторий.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Сейчас если в модуле 5 проектов, а изменения внесли в 3,то компмлируются только 3 проекта.

Comment: `выбор git vs svn, главным образом, зависит от интеллектуального уровня команды` – это очень субъективно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, может и так, но: а) я не встречал тех, кто за месяц не разобрался бы в svn б) видел как переход svn->git вызывал множество проблем при невысоком общем уровне команды в) видел как люди не понимают принципов работы git даже через несколько лет ежедневного использования г) как правило, команды с невысоким средним уровнем не ставят перед собой задачи, которые в git решаются проще чем в svn.